# does linear approximation of function around point x is the same as the linear approximation of function at points inside the region of point x?

Tags: calculus, limits

I want to ask that as we calculate the derivative at a point by fnding the linear approximation of the region around the point ,does that mean the derivative of points inside the region which we approximate linearly is the same as the derivative the point a[image]

Here we find the derivative at point a by approximating the region around point a by a linear function ,if we try to find the derivative of function at points that are inside the region (a,a+dx) then does the derivative of points inside these region will be the same as derivative of function at point a i.e
Is this true: $$f'(x)=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}= f'(x_i)=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$$
where $$\ \ x_i\in\mathbb{(x,x+h)}$$

Comment: It's unclear to me what your question actually is.  Are you looking for something like the [Mean Value Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem)?  And you cannot refer to a [bound variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_variables_and_bound_variables) like $h$ from "outside" the limit.

Comment: I am asking if the derivative of function at x will be equal to the derivative of function at point which directly next to point x in limit .

Comment: There is nothin like a *"point which directly next to point"* in real (or complex or rational) numbers. For any two points $x\neq y$ there are infinitely manypoints between them. And for functions like $f:x\mapsto x^2$ the derivative if $f'(x)=2x$.  This means that for any $x\neq y$ there is $f'(x)\neq f'(y)$ no matter how close $x$ and $y$ are. Or you mean that $f'(y)$ gets arbitrarily close to $f'(x)$ as $y$ approaches $x$? This basically means that $f'$ is continuous at $x$.

Comment: By directly next to the point i meant to ask if the points that come under the region around a certain point x which we approximate linearly has the same derivatve as the point x ,you know how we approximate region around a point  to find it derivative then I just asked if the derivative of the points inside the region ,which we approximate to find the derivative , will have the same derivative as the point x